# Uploading images to Cloudinary - Laravel

Tags: laravel, storage, image-uploading, cloudinary

In CloudinaryController im getting local file(image) from $request and upload it to Cloudinary

```
public static function uploadImage($path, $image_name, $id)
    {
       Cloudder::upload($path, $image_name);
       $image_url= Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId());
       $this->saveImage($image_url, $id); // saving url to DB
       return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Image Uploaded Successfully');
    }
```

How can i upload image with code above to directory home/users instead of home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudianry supports the `folder` parameter when [uploading](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference).

So you could set the `folder` parameter to `home/users` to have the image uploaded to that folder.

Although we don't support the [`cloudder` wrapper](https://github.com/jrm2k6/cloudder) officially it looks like you could add the `folder` parmaeter to `$options` in `cloudder`

i.e change `Cloudder::upload($path, $image_name);` to `Cloudder::upload($path, $options, $image_name);`

Answer (score 0):

Added parameter $folder and its working nice, thanks for help!

```
Cloudder::upload($path, $image_name, ['folder' => $folder]);
```